# How can I pass a parameter in string that is assigned to SVG in Angular ts file?

Tags: angular

I need to add parameter in err, that should be the image.
Here is what I have:

```
function err(){
   alert("test")
}
```

```
 OrgChart.templates["ula"].img_0 = 
'<clipPath id="{randId}">
    <circle cx="50" cy="60" r="40"></circle>
</clipPath>
<image onerror="' + err() + '" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#{randId})" xlink:href="{val}" x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" ></image>';
```

Or it is this in plain JS:

```
   OrgChart.templates.ula.img_0 = 
'<clipPath id="{randId}">
    <circle cx="50" cy="60" r="40"></circle>
</clipPath><image onerror="err(this)" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#{randId})" xlink:href="{val}" x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" ></image>';
```